# LWC to read, display and filter data from TCRM dataset

Tags: lightning-web-components, einstein-analytics, lwc-wire-adapter, crm-analytics

On my TCRM dashboard, I have a component that is hard to implement using the standard features and widgets of TCRM Analytics. On my web search, I stumbled [`lightning/analyticsWaveApi` Wire Adapters and Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_lightning_analytics_wave_api) and they look like they allow to read TCRM datasets from within LWC components.

1. Is there any **sample code** that shows a working example of this? Couldn't find anything on Github.
2. Should I embed such an LWC on a TCRM dashboard? Or can I **place it everywhere** where LWC components are allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the LWC component **both** in TCRM dashboard and Other places based on the configuration in `js-meta.xml`. The configuraton to add in TCRM dashboard explained [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_lwc_in_db.meta/bi_dev_guide_lwc_in_db/bi_lwc_in_db_hw_example_attributes.htm).

I did a simple POC based on the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_lightning_analytics_wave_api) and I am able to Query the Data from a TCRM Dataset. Here is the code below. There is nothing in the HTML and I have added to Home Page of the Sales App.

*JS Controller*

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import { getDataset,executeQuery } from 'lightning/analyticsWaveApi';
const idOrApiName = 'opportunity'; //Dataset API Name
export default class CrmAnalyticsDemo extends LightningElement {
    query;
    datasetId;
    datasetVersionId;    
    idOrApiName; // or fetch the ID or developer name
    @wire(getDataset, {
        datasetIdOrApiName: idOrApiName
    })
    onGetDataset({data, error}) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('ERROR : ',JSON.stringify(error));
        } else if (data) {
            this.datasetId = data.id;
            this.datasetVersionId = data.currentVersionId;
        }
    }    
    get computedQuery() {
        let query = `q = load "${this.datasetId}/${this.datasetVersionId}";`;
        query += `q = filter q by 'IsClosed' == "false";`;
        query += `q = foreach q generate 'Amount' as 'Amount', 'CloseDate' as 'CloseDate', 'ForecastCategoryName' as 'ForecastCategoryName', 'Name' as 'Name', 'Owner.Name' as 'Owner.Name', 'StageName' as 'StageName';`;
        query += `q = limit q 100`;
        this.query = query;
        if (!this.query) { return undefined; } 
        return {
            query: this.query
        }        
    }
    
    @wire(executeQuery, {
        query: '$computedQuery'
    })
    onExecuteQuery({data, error}) {
       if (error) {
        console.log('ERROR : ',JSON.stringify(error));
       } else if (data) {
         console.log('executeQuery results RESPONSE:', JSON.stringify(data.results.records));
         console.log('executeQuery metadata RESPONSE:', JSON.stringify(data.results.metadata));
       }
    }
}
```

*Console Output*
[image]

I need to check for the third point. Also, there is a developer's guide available for the [*Lightning Web Components in CRM Analytics Dashboards*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_lwc_in_db.meta/bi_dev_guide_lwc_in_db/bi_lwc_in_db_overview.htm).

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful answer. There are very few documentations and implementations. The above example was helpful. Upvoted!